# Loops in Time-Series-Cross-Section Data in R

Tags: r, loops, panel-data

I have been struggling for a while with my time-series cross-sectional dataset now, especially in trying to find a way to define the maximum value of one column for every country and year. I tried different versions of for and if/else loops, but didn't really succeed. Could you maybe help me with any leads?

This would be a small reproducible example for my data structure:

```
country <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c")
year <- c(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007)
topic <-c("u", "v", "w", "x","y","z","u", "v", "w", "x","y","z","u", "v", "w", "x","y","z")
perc <-c(0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0,0,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0, 0.2)
dta <- data.frame(country, year, topic, perc)
```

In the end, I would like to have created a new variable stating the topic with the highest percentage in a given year and country:

```
topicmax <-c("v","v","v","v","v","v","v","v","v","v","v","v","x","x","x","x","x","x")
```

Preferable I would also generate another variable specifying the exact percentage of the topic with the highest perc-value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. All tutorials on Loops that I found don't tackle time-series cross-sectional issues... Thanks!

Comment: Hint: don't use loops. Look in to packages like data.table or dplyr.

Comment: I tried with data.table before but wasn't successful - this is the code I used - does that make any sense?  ans = dta[, list(count=.N, mperc=max(perc)), keyby=list(country, year)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach the problem is with `which.max`. It locates the index position of the maximum value. That index can be used to subset `topic`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dta)[, topicmax := topic[which.max(perc)], by=country]
#     country year topic perc topicmax
#  1:       a 2002     u  0.3        v
#  2:       a 2003     v  0.4        v
#  3:       a 2004     w  0.1        v
#  4:       a 2005     x  0.2        v
#  5:       a 2006     y  0.0        v
#  6:       a 2007     z  0.0        v
#  7:       b 2002     u  0.2        v
#  8:       b 2003     v  0.3        v
#  9:       b 2004     w  0.1        v
# 10:       b 2005     x  0.1        v
# 11:       b 2006     y  0.1        v
# 12:       b 2007     z  0.2        v
# 13:       c 2002     u  0.1        x
# 14:       c 2003     v  0.2        x
# 15:       c 2004     w  0.2        x
# 16:       c 2005     x  0.3        x
# 17:       c 2006     y  0.0        x
# 18:       c 2007     z  0.2        x
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks a lot! For future reference - if I would want to have it by country and year, I know I can just create a new variable that includes both information as by variable, but is there also a more elegant way?

Comment: I don't think you have to create a new variable. Try `by=.(country, year)`